# AWS Aurora auto scaling causes Incorrect arguments to mysqld_stmt_execute

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, autoscaling, amazon-aurora

We are running AWS Aurora(Serverless RDS) in our production environment. It has to scale between 2 capacity units(4GB RAM) and 8 capacity units(16GB RAM).

For the last 2 months, our database has never auto-scaled, it was running in the minimum capacity unit. In the past week, due to an increase in system usage, auto-scaling started triggering every few mins. It was scaling between 4 and 8 capacity units during the day time.

And since last week, we were getting an issue(not all the time but every few mins) when our application triggers SQL queries to the database, **Incorrect arguments to mysqld_stmt_execute**. This error happens for both read & write operations.

So, we suspected auto-scaling might be the reason and we kept the same capacity units for both min(8) and max(8) to avoid scaling. So, scaling didn't happen and we didn't get that error again. So, we confirmed that the error was caused by auto-scaling. Actually, auto-scaling helped us to reduce the cost but unfortunately causes an error.

We don't understand why this error happens during scaling. Can someone explain why scaling causes this issue and how to avoid this?

Or is it something related to connection pooling issue? I've raised it in the connection pooling project as well.

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/1407

Comment: Sounds like you have nailed it down to an AWS bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem with caching prepared statements. When new servers are provisioned for scaling and when the cached prepared statements are fired on the new servers, MySQL has thrown this error. So, **we disabled prepared statement caches** and we are not getting the error anymore.

Though it works, we couldn't cache the prepared statements which may lag slight performance. As of now, it's okay as we didn't notice the lag.